# How can we find the solution of the Cauchy problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the problem: $$\\u_t-\Delta u=f(t,x) \text{ in } (0,T) \times \mathbb{R}^n \\ u(0,x)=\phi(x), x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

we have that a solution of this is the following: $$u(t,x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Gamma(t,x-\xi)\phi(\xi) d{\xi}+\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Gamma(t-\tau,x-\xi) f(\tau, \xi) d{\xi} d{\tau}$$

given that $f$ is Hölder continuous at each bounded subset of $(0,T) \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and bounded in $(0,T) \times \mathbb{R}^n$.

When we have the following problem, how can we find its solution in a closed form?
$$\\u_t-\Delta u+cu=f(t,x) \text{ in } (0,T) \times \mathbb{R}^n \\ u(0,x)=\phi(x), x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

$c \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant

Do we use somehow the solution of the heat equation above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two hints to get you started.  First hint:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} [ e^{at} h(t,x) ] = e^{at} \partial_t h(t,x) + e^{at} a h(t,x) \\
= e^{at}[\partial_t h(t,x) + a h(t,x) ].
$$
Second hint:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} [ e^{at} h(t,x) ] = e^{at} \partial_{x_i}h(t,x).
$$

Comment: So we pick a function $v$ such that $v=e^{ct} u(t,x)$ and then we will have the equation $v_t-\Delta v=e^{ct} f(t,x)$ with the condition $v(0,x)=\phi(x)$, right? @Glitch

Comment: Yes, that will do the job.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much!!! @Glitch

Comment: Hi @Glitch Do you maybe have also an idea about my other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053129/do-we-deduce-that-the-function-is-bounded-by-an-arbitrary-constant ?